# How to generate css using google chrome inspector to further use them?

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

Good evening, i was debugging my jsf page behavior, so i opened google chrome inspector and start checking/unchecking some options and the appearance of the page changed, i want to create a new css file from all the options that i checked and and save these file to use it in my web application, could any one tell me how to do that?

Comment: As far as I know there is no convenient way to do this besides copying the styles directly out of the inspector's Elements window.  Usually when I do this I just keep track of which elements I'm editing then update my CSS accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing css properties you could click on the link to the source file for a particular rule. [image: screenshot]

As a result DevTools will show you Source panel with the file.
You could inspect the changes via *Local Modifications* context menu or save the file with help of *Save*/Save As*.

[image: screenshot 2]

Answer (score 0):

There is [this](http://addyosmani.com/blog/autosave-changes-chrome-dev-tools/) plugin which can get you quite far and then there is and there should be some other way explained in [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N8SS-rUEZPg&t=8m20s) video (can't watch from where I am right now).